# effective assignment of drivers and fuel carrier

Tags: puzzle

There are 101 men, some of them are drivers and some of them are fuel carrier. 
each car can carries enough fuel for a single race. How do we maximize the number of race?

attempt: 
let $x$ be the number of drivers, $y$ be number of fuel carriers. 
$x+y=101$, and we want to maximize $x+xy$. I would go with $x=51$ and $y=50$ this is just my feeling.

Is this right?

Comment: I don't understand how the word problem (first paragraph) translates into maximizing $x+xy$, but if you want to maximize $x+xy = x(y+1)$ subject to $x+(y+1)=102$ then yeah the optimal is when $x = y+1 = 51$.

Comment: This is because each fuel carrier can provide to more than one car!